# How should I remove this crankset?

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket

I recently acquired a 10 year old Cube Acid MTB which I intend to refurbish and convert to an ebike.

I need to remove the crankset and purchased a crank puller.

It seems to be a universal size but the "internal" bolt which should push against the bottom bracket spindle to release the crank arm seems too thin, and just slots straight inside the bottom bracket hole.

(Click images for larger views)

[image: View through the crank]

[image: Close-up of the threads on the crank]

[image: Crank puller sitting inside the crank without engaging]

Are there other sizes/types of crank puller?

Comment: That looks like a splined hollow bottom bracket spindle, so maybe Octalink I? (not to be confused with Octalink II/Hollowtech). There are Octalink/ISIS-specific puller tools (now harder to find) e.g. the Park Tool CCP-44 Crank Puller. I think the Octalink/ISIS uses 22mm threading diameter.

Comment: Thanks @armand - would this help? Silverline 241095 Crank Removal Tool Square Taper and ISIS Threads https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00J3AA7OM

Comment: IIRC, the two classes are square taper and Octalink/ISIS, so ISIS is good in the title. Looking at its photos, it has a wider end plate adapter, which hopefully should push against your spindle.

Comment: Will give it a try, cheers

Comment: I too had a feeling that this might be an Octalink crankset, noting the 8 grooves in the opening. @Armand consider adding your comment as an answer.

Comment: Tidied it up into an answer. Turn of the century hardtail knowledge comes in handy again! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue seems to be that what is considered "universal" changes over time.
The OP seems to have a crank puller that is universal for square-taper bottom brackets.

The photo looks like a splined hollow bottom bracket spindle, so maybe Octalink I? (not to be confused with Octalink II/Hollowtech). There are Octalink/ISIS-specific puller tools (now harder to find) e.g. the Park Tool CCP-44 Crank Puller. The difference seems to be not with the threading, but rather having a larger-diameter "pusher" end that seats on the hollow spindle's end rather than just going inside.

Apparently current "universal" crank pullers include such an alternate pusher end and "universality" is restored :)

Example only photo of a crank puller with two alternate pusher inserts:

[image]